# Write file to Download directory in Android

Tags: java, android, file, io

Below is my code

```
    File downloadsDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

    long currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String filename = "downloaded_image_" + currentTimestamp + ".png";

    File imageFile = new File(downloadsDirectory, filename);

    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        outputStream.write(imageBytes);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

I have added permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Now my code above works fine on Android 12.

But it fails on Android 8 and Android 10, with error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/downloaded_image_1697897803982.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Looking at the internet, I am told the below code should work on all API (greater than 24), but doesnt the below code imply that my code should not work on Android 12, and work on Android 8/9? I dont understand, how is my code (above code), is working on Android 12, but not on 8/9, but below is supposed to work.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
  StorageManager storageManager = getSystemService(StorageManager.class);
  StorageVolume storageVolume = storageManager.getStorageVolumes().get(0);
  File downloadsDirectory = storageVolume.getDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

  long currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
  String filename = "downloaded_image_" + currentTimestamp + ".png";

  File imageFile = new File(downloadsDirectory, filename);

  try {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    outputStream.write(imageBytes);
    outputStream.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
} else {
  File downloadsDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

  long currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
  String filename = "downloaded_image_" + currentTimestamp + ".png";

  File imageFile = new File(downloadsDirectory, filename);

  try {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    outputStream.write(imageBytes);
    outputStream.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: looks like the main difference is download Directory. i guess access the download Directory is difference based on different versions of android.

Answer (score 0):

Android 10 introduced scoped storage, which restricts how apps can access external storage. To make your code work across different Android versions, you should consider checking the runtime permission, especially for Android 10 and above.

Here's an updated version of your code that works on Android 8, 9, 10, and newer.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    // Android 10 and above
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME, filename);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

    Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Uri itemUri = contentResolver.insert(contentUri, contentValues);

    if (itemUri != null) {
        try {
            OutputStream outputStream = contentResolver.openOutputStream(itemUri);
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.write(imageBytes);
                outputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create a file in the Downloads directory.");
    }
} else {
    // Android 8 and 9
    File downloadsDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

    if (!downloadsDirectory.exists()) {
        downloadsDirectory.mkdirs();
    }

    long currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String filename = "downloaded_image_" + currentTimestamp + ".png";

    File imageFile = new File(downloadsDirectory, filename);

    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        outputStream.write(imageBytes);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw a RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```